# Shifts overlapping found

Tags: sql-server

i am using sql server and want to save shifts data without overlapping.
My table have StartDateTime and EndDateTime column, and these shifts will be most likely for weeks and/or months,(not daily bases).
i.e. each row have 1 month Morning,Evening and Night Shift (for example).
I need sql query which give result if overlapping found, so i did't allow user/UI to add Overlapped data.

thanks,
Najjay

Comment: Can you provide some sample data please?

Comment: Dear bviale,
      i use this query,


SELECT TimeslotID FROM [AvlGroupTimeslots] WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE 
GroupCategoryId=@GroupCategoryID AND IsActive=1 AND 
(CONVERT(TIME,SlotStartTime) <= CONVERT(TIME,@slotEndTime)  AND CONVERT(TIME,SlotEndTime) >= CONVERT(TIME,@slotStartTime)) AND 
(CONVERT(DATE,SlotStartTime) <= CONVERT(DATE,@slotEndTime)  AND CONVERT(DATE,SlotEndTime) >= CONVERT(DATE,@slotStartTime)) 
AND (TimeSlotID <> 0 AND TimeSlotID <> @timeSlotID)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select 1 
from shiftsTable
where (startdate <= @startDate and endDate >= @endDate)
or
(startdate >= @startDate and endDate <= @endDate)
or
(startdate <= @startDate and endDate <= @endDate)
```

Problem still exists, if i make night shift, i.e. from 10:00 PM to next days Morning 06:00 AM.Morning and after noon shifts are ok.

Comment: what is the type of columns "SlotStartTime" and "SlotEndTime"? These should be of type "datetime" for the query to work. Also value to be compared should be of type "datetime" too.

Comment: datatype of these two(SlotStartTime,SlotEndTime) columns is DateTime.
SP is also take these are params as datetime, i.e.

Comment: In my query, replace '>' with '>=' and '<' with '<=' and check again.